# Allowing connections to Microsoft Server on port 11111

Tags: azure, windows-server, azure-virtual-network, windows-firewall, windows-server-2022

This is admittedly a very beginner question on Microsoft Server, so please assume basic knowledge. I do, however, feel I have a good knowledge of Linux networking concepts, but I am failing miserably with Microsoft.

So, I am attempting to open up a port connection to my running Microsoft Server on port 11111 to connect to a running web application on that port. From within the Remote Desktop Program I am able to connect to the port on 127.0.0.1 and localhost.

[image]

So, I have confirmed that the app server is working and can send responses on port 11111.

However, I couldn't connect to this from outside the RDP instance, let's say I have been allocated the IP address 100.01.02.03 for argument sake. I navigate to 100.01.02.03:11111 in the browser, and the connection hangs.

So, what I have diagnosed is that the port is closed to outside connections. I followed some nice guides on how to open a port in Windows Server Firewall, and opened the port following the relevant documentation:

[image]

I am confident that this is correct.

As my Microsoft Server is via an Azure Cloud instance, I have also added the inbound port rule to the Network security group associated to the VM running the server as follows:

[image]

However, I still can not connect to 100.01.02.03:11111 from another device.

Being a hobbyist, I am not sure what else I would need to do. What debugging or diagnosing can I do, or are there documentation or guides to be able to get this connection working?

Answer (score 0):

•   According to **Security and Compliance analysis, the port 11111 was a very vulnerable port as viruses and trojans used this port to infiltrate and communicate with internal services in the system. Thus, an extra layer of security and cautiousness based on the global security outlook is enforced on these types of flagged ports**.

Thus, if you want to **allow communication on this port for the VM’s IP address, then ensure that the ‘Allow’ inbound traffic rule in the VM’s respective NSG is at a priority higher than the ‘Deny’ rule for all other ports in the inbound port list** as below: -

[image: Inbound connection port rule]

[image: Port priority]

Once done, then **ensure that there is no ‘NRMS-Zero Trust’ Corpnet network policy defined for the tenant** as shown in the below snapshot: -

Since, you have **allowed the inbound traffic for that port through the OS Windows firewall, by configuring the above given points, you should be able to connect to the VM’s IP address through that port 11111**.

Finally, try to **check the connectivity through the ‘Connection troubleshoot’ option as shown below by entering the source and destination IP address correctly over the required port and protocol**: -

[image: Connection troubleshoot]

[image: Zero trust policy]

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/299000/i-want-to-access-custom-port-of-my-vm-on-azure-via.html***